# One Database Multiple Applications + Performance

Tags: performance, web-services, scalability

I have a database that I would like to be used by (n) number of applications.

This database sits behind a Webservice - So all CRUD operations call the respective webservice methods.

I will use a ticket based application as an example, although I'd imagine this could be expanded to most types of applications.

Let's say Site A - Is a site where tickets and events can be displayed and sold. Also Site A allows Authorized and Authenticated Users to add/remove events and tickets.

Let's say we also have Site B - Site B can only display and sell tickets and events. It cannot add or remove tickets and events.

Both sites are using the same database and webservice.

My question is - Is this a viable approach that will scale well? Is the single database a wise approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what is the difference between "sell event" and "add event". The typical approaches for database scaling are:

1. Separate read and write calls. Write to single DB, read from multiple replicas
2. Separate entities to different databases. For example, store events in one database and tickets in another one.

Single database is a fine solution for a lot of applications. My suggestion is not to spend to mach on scaling at the beginning of your project, but keep in mind some ways how to scale it if required. It is nice that you have a single frontend to your database - in future you can add some logic there (like DB replication etc) and websites will use the same API without changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I wasn't aware of those approaches for database scaling, thanks for that. A sell event is basically that the site can sell tickets. Site B can only sell - there would be no admin section that would allow tickets to be inserted or updated.